How to make small package (new style) in notebook for testing?
Sometimes it is easier to test package inside notebook without having to make .m file and read it each time. This can be  done using the official package style like this
In new cell we type
BeginPackage["mypkg`"]
dsolve::usage = "mypkg`dsolve ode";

Begin["`Private`"]
dsolve[ode_] := Module[{},
   Print["In mypkg`dsolve"]
   ];
End[];
EndPackage[];

And now in new cell
sol = mypkg`dsolve[ode]

This works. But with the new package style, I can't do the same. First of all, there is only Package["mypkg"]` and there is no corresponding way to close the package. So it seems this is only designed to be in a file?
And Mathematica reads until of end of file and then it knows the package is finished? That is the same as having  EndPackage[]; in the current package style?
When writing in new cell with fresh kernel the following new style package
Package["mypkg`"]
PackageExport["dsolve"]

dsolve[ode_] := Module[{},
  Print["In mypkg`dsolve"]
  ]

And evaluating the above cell, Mathematica gives lots of errors

And nothing gets defined and can't call my function in the package.
But if I put the above exact code in an .m file in same folder and do Get on it, now the package works:
Get["mypkg.m"]
mypkg`dsolve[ode]


Is there a way to define the new style package inside notebook like with the current package style? (in one cell)
This is just for doing quick testing. At the end of course will copy code to .m file.
Or does one have to use .m files only with the new package style?
V 14
